# Cordova Blackberry update to 10.3.1 - AJAX POST JSON returns Data null

Tags: ajax, json, cordova, blackberry, blackberry-10

I am developing an app for BlackBerry 10 using cordova.

Since I updated my BlackBerry OS from 10.2.1 to 10.3.1 I have the following problem: When I do a Ajax Post with JSON I don't get a data result, but step into the success function.

My code looks like this:

```
window.jQuery.ajax({
url: "http://myurl.com/systemservice.asmx/ServiceName",
data: "{'DataName':'DataValue'}",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
   alert(data);
   //Do something else with data.d
}});
```

The alert returns "null".

Testing the App in a web Browser (also build it as Browser App with cordova) works fine. Even with the old Version of BlackBerry OS it worked fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of my Cordova apps running on 10.3.1 and they seem to still work fine... though I'm using Angular's $http to make the calls.

I would start by trying to build the app with WebInspector enabled (use the WebWorks SDK GUI, or it's the -d flag while building, I think) to check the console for errors. Or use this tidbit to echo console output into alert messages:

```
var _log = console.log,
    _warn = console.warn,
    _error = console.error;

console.log = function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(arguments));
    return _log.apply(console, arguments);
};

console.warn = function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(arguments));
    return _warn.apply(console, arguments);
};

console.error = function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(arguments));
    return _error.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

Good luck!